# SignalR & IE Issue - poll is pending

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a Problem With IE and SignalR, I'm using the it to perform a Syncing action between two databases, the Actions Completed successfully on Google Chrome / Firefox / Safari in all scenarios.

Using IE for the First time the sync performed successfully but only for one time, in the second time a pending request stack and the page stay freeze for ever.
I found a solution online which is changing the transport mode.
But page still freezing.

```
if (isIE()) {
   $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['serverSentEvents','foreverFrame']}).done(function () {
       progressNotifier.server.DoMyLongAction();
   });
}else{
   $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['serverSentEvents','longPolling'] }).done(function () {
       progressNotifier.server.DoMyLongAction();
   });
}
```

I'm Using:
SgnalR v2.1.0.0
.Net framework v4.5
jquery v1.8

is it an Issue or I'm Doing something wrong ?

**Edit**

my application use Jquery progress bar  and i Update this progress bar using this Code:
server side:

```
Clients.Caller.sendMessage(msg, 5, "Accounts");
```

client side:

```
progressNotifier.client.sendMessage = function (message, value, Entity) {
      pbar1.progressbar("value", nvalue);
};
```

it's working on Firefox so I thought it's a signalR Issue !! Now i became confused if it's working as expected then what causes this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you found online is not likely to help your issue.

I doubt your `IsIE()` function is correctly identifying IE. If it was, SignalR should only be attempting to establish a "foreverFrame" connection, since IE does not even support "serverSentEvents". I would not expect IE to make any "/signalr/poll" requests, because those requests are only made by the "longPolling" transport.

Also, having a "pending" poll request in the IE F12 tool's network tab is entirely expected. This is how [*long* polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)#Ajax_with_long_polling) is designed to work. Basically, as soon as a message is received the client makes a new ajax request (a long poll) to retrieve new messages. If no new messages are immediately available, the server will wait (for up to 110 seconds by default in the case of SignalR, not forever) for a new message to be sent to the client before responding to the pending long poll request with the new message.

Can you clarify exactly what issue you are having other than seeing a pending poll request showing up under the network tab? It would also help if you you [enabled tracing in the JS client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#javascript), provided the console output, and showed *all* the "/signalr/..." requests in the network tab.

Comment: you Was right the IsIE() function was not working correctly on IE11, However the pending issue still there but in different way "/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame..." and a ping appear in the console every few minute. I copied the Solution to Different server and it's working there fine, and I tried to Do an IIS reset and Clear browser cache... is there something else I missed ?, Both server Use the same .net framework 4.5

Comment: As with long polling, you would expect to see pending "/signalr/connect?transport=foreverFrame..." requests. /ping requests are also  expected every 5 minutes. Without going into what you're seeing in the network tab, can you explain what is actually going wrong with you application? What's the unexpected behavior?

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? it doesnt even solve the problem

Comment: The answer is that a pending SignalR request in the network tab is not a problem, it's the expected behavior.

Comment: @halter73 So how do we reduce the default wait time? id like to reduce it to around 10.

Comment: @Kendo Sorry for the late reply. That would be the `ConnectionTimeout`. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Configuring-SignalR

Comment: @halter73 I've tried to use ServerSideEvents after WebSockets and the result from server has never been returned. After 90 sec I just got the message "rror: ServerSentEvents failed: Error: EventSource failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the connection ID is not present on the server, or a proxy is refusing/buffering the connection." and that's it.. Server side did not reveal any problems either.

Answer (score 1):

you can try use `EventSource` (SSE).

I am using this:
https://github.com/remy/polyfills/blob/master/EventSource.js
but modified, for SignalR:
http://a7.org/scripts/jquery/eventsource_edited.js

I am working with it for  one year, SignalR just check for `window.EventSource` and it works.