# window.print stuck because of long-polling

Tags: javascript, printing, signalr, long-polling

I have a website which uses signalR and has a print button.

My clients’ browsers are Chrome 32/36 which don’t support web sockets, so signalR uses long-polling. But since the request only returns once every 60 seconds, when the user clicks the print button it doesn’t work until the request is finished.

Is there any work-around to this? Maybe cancel the request somehow?

P.S.: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> work just fine.

Comment: Not sure if it would help but why isn't SignalR using serverSentEvents?

Comment: @Pawel That version does not support them

Comment: You may try the foreverFrame transport but am not sure if it will allow you to do that...

Comment: @Pawel Forever Frame is Internet explorer only. His clients are Chrome users.

Comment: You can reduce the wait time to whatever you want, have a look at this document: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Configuring-SignalR Also have a look at this question, there is a good explanation of how this works, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378733/signalr-ie-issue-poll-is-pending/26392362#26392362

Comment: @Kendo - this is not accurate. As per https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/799d9bc32524066344cb3656e5f28f2fd03ba9b3/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.transports.foreverFrame.js#L83-L84 forever frame is excluded when eventSource is not supported instead of checking the browser. So it should work in Chrome if the version they use don't support eventSource.

Comment: @Pawel The Microsoft SignalR documentation states that its Internet explorer only http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr Search forever frame in the text its the first hit. Also if eventSource is not supported I think it defaults to long polling

Comment: @Kendo - I showed you code. The point  is not that longPolling is not the default (it is) the point is that you can use foreverframe if the browser does not support eventSource.

Comment: @Pawel Apologies you are correct. There does indeed appear to be a workaround for the use of forever frames in browsers other than Internet Explorer where SSE is not supported.